# RectJs | Get a parameter value from url omitting null values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url

Can someone please help me with this? I am getting "fruit" parameter's value from the URL in reactJs.
As for example, if My URL is like:

http://localhost:3001/buy?fruit=&fruit=1&fruit=&fruit=

any one of these four "fruit" parameter can contain the value. (only one have a value.)(here the second parameter contains the value, it depends on the clients preference. )

it can be either,
http://localhost:3001/buy?fruit=1&fruit=&fruit=&fruit=(here the first parameter has the value)
http://localhost:3001/buy?fruit=&fruit=&fruit=1&fruit= (here the third parameter has the value)
http://localhost:3001/buy?fruit=&fruit=&fruit=&fruit=1 (here the fort parameter has the value.)

The URL has some null values as I have pre from inputs which are null.

How to omit these null values and get the parameter value?

here's the code segment where I get data from URL:

```
let myfruit = (new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)).get("fruit")
```

this returns null value and not the parameter value.

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 0):

I personally have used URL searchParams

```
let url = new URL('http://localhost:3001/buy?fruit=&fruit=1&fruit=&fruit=')
let fruitParam = url.searchParams.getAll('fruit').filter(x => x)
```

The `.filter` bit is optional to remove null values.

Comment: HI! my url is dynamic. any of these four parameters can contain the value. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: This code should pick up any non-null parameter values.